# Ошибка в Selenium: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Появляется ошибка при запуске: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
Во время выполнения в IDE всё отлично, а если создать jar файл и попробовать запустить то эта ошибка. Тестировалось на macos и windows. Находил информацию, что дело в версии guava, обновил до последней, всё так же. Есть мысль что какая то библиотека просто не экспортируется в jar. Подскажите как запустить.

ОС: macOS, Windows; Браузер: Firefox 54; Selenium 3.4.0; geckodriver 0.18; guava 22; IDE: intellij idea 2017.2.1;

Драйвер создаю так:

```
public Driver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.mainDriver", "geckodriver");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

[image: Скрин Modules - Dependencies]

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

Помогло выставление библиотеки `guava` на первое место в файле `.iml`.